# Can't store all requests

Tags: php, laravel

I have course / questions / answers.
Course have sections.
So questions have course_id, section_id and question columns. and answers have answer_id, answer and correct columns.
I store everything except course_id, course_id is stored NULL.
So i why i'm not getting course_id? whats i'm doing wrong?

```
$course = Course::find(request()->get('courseId'));
$section =  $course->sections()->find(request()->get('sectionId'));

$data = request()->validate([
    'questions.*.question' => 'required',
    'questions.*.answers.*.answer' => 'required',
    'questions.*.answers.*.correct' => '',
], [
    'questions.*.question.required' => '',
    'questions.*.answers.*.answer.required' => ''
]);

foreach ($data['questions'] as $key => $q) {
    $question = $section->questions()->create(['question' => $q['question']]);
    $question->answers()->createMany($data['questions'][$key]['answers']);
}
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Maybe check if the fields are fillable in your models, you will find more informations here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts

Comment: Fields are fillable. i think i'm having problem in first or second line of the code...

Comment: can you dump your $data with dd($data) to debug?

Comment: Not sure to understand your database, course have sections, but you store section_id in the question ?

Comment: Courses/Sections/Lessons |  questions / answers  |  questions = course_id / section_id / question   |||   dd($data)   array:1 [▼
  "questions" => array:1 [▼
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "question" => "sadsadas"
      "answers" => array:1 [▼
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "answer" => "dasdasdsad"
          "correct" => "1"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]

Comment: It's so easy that  no one is answering? :d

Comment: Please edit your post with additional logs, dumps etc. Otherwise this question is hardly answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$fillable` array in `Question` model contain `course_id` like this
`protected $fillable = [...., course_id, ...]` or remove `course_id` from `$guarded` array if it contain it.

Comment: Thanks for response i just added after all function will be done ```   $question->update([
        'course_id' => $course->id
        ]); ``` then i add course_id.  I think it is not the right way to do it but don't it's working now : )